# How to reference array id to another collection

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have one collection as Devices and another as Schedulers. Devices contains appliances as an array and now each of them has object id which I want to use as reference in my new schema named as Schedulers.

This is what I am asking:

```
var SchedulerSchema = new Schema({ applianceId: {
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Device.appliances'
});
```

What should be ref if I need to link appliances field which is an array inside my Device collection.

Answer (score 0):

a small example on how to reference.

Population is the process of automatically replacing the specified paths in the document with document(s) from other collection(s). We may populate a single document, multiple documents, plain object, multiple plain objects, or all objects returned from a query. Let's look at some examples.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
  , Schema = mongoose.Schema

var personSchema = Schema({
  _id     : Number,
  name    : String,
  age     : Number,
  stories : [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Story' }]
});

var storySchema = Schema({
  _creator : { type: Number, ref: 'Person' },
  title    : String,
  fans     : [{ type: Number, ref: 'Person' }]
});

var Story  = mongoose.model('Story', storySchema);
var Person = mongoose.model('Person', personSchema);
```

So far we've created two Models. Our Person model has its stories field set to an array of ObjectIds. The ref option is what tells Mongoose which model to use during population, in our case the Story model. All _ids we store here must be document _ids from the Story model. We also declared the Story _creator property as a Number, the same type as the _id used in the personSchema. It is important to match the type of _id to the type of ref.

**Note:** *ObjectId, Number, String, and Buffer are valid for use as refs.*

go through the link for more info : http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

Comment: this doesnot provide the answer to the questions

Comment: yes the example shows a solution that would work from the asker. are we supposed to do the coding for them or show a direction that would work ?

Comment: I think that he asked how to reference an item in an array, not create a attribute that  references another model